# RecyclerView showing one item only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'am working with RecyclerView but when items viewed in the recyclerview only the first item in the list is shown
***here's the RecyclerView Adapter***

```
 package com.example.abdelmagied.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by AbdELMagied on 7/19/2017.
 */
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<items> myitems;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<items> myitems) {
        this.myitems = myitems;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewrow , parent , false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.name.setText(myitems.get(position).name);
        holder.price.setText(myitems.get(position).price);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myitems.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
         TextView name;
         TextView price;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewname);
            price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewprice);
        }
    }
}
```

**here's the layout which named recyclerviewrow.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewname" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewprice" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**here's the Main3Activity.xml**

```
 package com.example.abdelmagied.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
       public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mymanager;
        public RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
            Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
            ArrayList<items> myitems = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("myarray");
            ArrayList<items> go = new ArrayList<items>();
             go.add(new items("mobile" , " blablabl" , "655"));
            go.add(new items("labtop" , " blablabl" , "655"));
            go.add(new items("sony" , "blablbl" , "655"));
            go.add(new items("mobile" , " blablabla" , "655"));
            go.add(new items("mobile" , "blablabla" , "655"));
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
            mymanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mymanager);
            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this , go);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is `match_parent`, change your parent item `android:layout_height` to wrap_content.

Now also you will have item but it will be at the bottom, if you scroll you can see the second item.

So change like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your recyclerviewrow.xml, change the LinearLayout height to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give you LinearLayout a minWidth and set the width to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewname" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewprice" />
</LinearLayout>
```